# The best practice to patch camlp4?

Tags: ocaml, camlp4

Commit patches and wait for INRIA to merge takes a long time and my work was always delayed. So I made a branch of camlp4.But everytime I made a little change, I need to make the whole compiler, it takes a long time. What's your best practice? (sorry If  I made a stupid mistake)

(I think branching camlp4 is relatively safe, at least, you are assured binary compatible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why you need to "make the whole compiler"; you should be able to recompile just the part that changed, that is Camlp4. `make camlp4out` (or `camlp4opt`) should be enough.

You [have suggested](http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=5665) on the OCaml bug tracker to separate Camlp4 from the OCaml distribution. If you maintain a fork anyway, why don't you try doing this on your side? I mean you could maintain a patch of OCaml that removes Camlp4 (... but still work, that is probably not so easy as it seems, but if you're ready to hack Camlp4 you're hard-necked anyway), and a separate distribution of Camlp4; that would solve your problem -- you'd still have to merge the OCaml trunk development in your ocaml-without-camlp4 fork.

Finally, have you considered discussing this with Jérémie Dimino? He's the current maintainer of Camlp4 (working on his free time, like other OCaml contributors), and he would probably be a good person to contact on those issues.

Comment: Thanks. I did make camlp4out, but the makefile seems not that smart.make camlp4out still takes some time. https://bitbucket.org/HongboZhang/ocaml/src

Comment: Is it possible for people outside INRIA to contribute?

Comment: Yes indeed; Jérémie, the Camlp4 maintainer, is not INRIA -- as far as I know. Anyone is free to submit a patch on the bugtracker, and it can go in if the maintainers like it. That said, Camlp4 changes, in particular ambitious and/or compatibility-breaking changes, will certainly have a hard life. You need to discuss that upfront, as in any software project.